# Customize url format of Angularjs's $location.search

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to change the url that `$location.search(params)` creates, without changing the functionality at all? For instance, can `/page?movie=836` be changed to something like `/page/movie/836`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `$location.search()` just grab the *query* part of the URL and parse it for convenience. Or as setter it updates the query part of the browser URL.

You can transform the `search()` literal to "REST" form and redirect by using `$location.url()` :

if `$location.path() ==  /page?movie=836`

---

```
var url = $location.path()
for (var key in $location.search()) {
  url += '/' + key + '/'+ $location.search()[key]
}   

$location.url( url ) // redirect to /path/movie/836
```